# C#. How can I give all labels in my form the same name, so if an object bounds with one of the labels that it will show something

Tags: c#, label, bounds

I am making a little game with c#.
But i have a lot of labels in my form and if an object bounds with one of
the labels it most return a textbox, but it is too much code to write that.
So, how can I give all the labels one name?

This is what I have now, but when I move my object(label) it will show MessageBoxes
without Boundsing with other labels:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (mUp == true) player.Top -= 1;
            if (mDown == true) player.Top += 1;
            if (mLeft == true) player.Left -= 1;
            if (mRight == true) player.Left += 1;

            foreach (var allLabels in this.Controls)
                if (allLabels is Label)
                    if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith((allLabels as Label).Bounds))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("hi");
                        break;
                    }
        }
```

[this is what happens if I set a breakpoint on the MessageBox.Show line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMyDF.png)

Comment: You can't give labels the same name.  Just write a loop that enumerates the label controls, or put the controls of interest into an array or collection and work with them there.

Answer (score 0):

Does this logic apply to every `Label` on the form?  If so then you can find them dynamically in the `Controls` collection.  Perhaps something like this:

```
foreach (var label in this.Controls)
    if (label is Label)
        if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith((label as Label).Bounds))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
            break;
        }
```

Or without the loops and nesting:

```
if (this.Controls.Where(c => c is Label).Any(c => player.Bounds.IntersectsWith((c as Label).Bounds)))
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
```

Or if there's only a *subset* of labels to which this applies then you can store them explicitly in a collection on the class (perhaps in the constructor) and then loop over that collection.  Same logic, but you'd loop over your collection instead of over `this.Controls`.

Depending on how much you want to abstract this, another option could be to create your own class (perhaps called something like `IntersectableLabel`) which inherits from `Label`.  Make all of your relevant labels instances of that class instead of `Label`.  (I'm not sure what effect this may have on the forms designer honestly, it's been a very long time since I've used Windows Forms.)  Then you can loop over `this.Controls` and look for `is IntersectableLabel`, which would filter out any labels you don't want to use.

Note that if your labels are ever nested in other controls then you may need a recursive function instead of a simple loop.

Comment: You can simplify this with `foreach var control in this.Controls) {if (control is Label label) { if //the rest is the same`

Comment: I have tried your method but when I move my object it will show the MessageBox without boundsing with antoher label.

Comment: @celalk38: That implies it's intersecting with a label.  What is the exact code you wrote?  (You can update your question to include that.)  When you debug, which label is triggering the intersection?  What are the bounds values on the player and on the label?

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (mUp == true) player.Top -= 1;
            if (mDown == true) player.Top += 1;
            if (mLeft == true) player.Left -= 1;
            if (mRight == true) player.Left += 1;

            foreach (var allLabels in this.Controls)
                if (allLabels is Label)
                    if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith((allLabels as Label).Bounds))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("hi");
                        break;
                    }
        }

Comment: @celalk38: When you debug, place a breakpoint on the line which shows the message box.  When you get to that line, what are the Bounds for `player` and for `allLabels`?  Do they intersect?  Which label is it on your form?

Comment: i have updated my question with a screenshot of what happens if I set a breakpoint on that line

Comment: @celalk38: And what are the bounds of that label?  Do they intersect?  The math seems to think they do, and it’s usually right about these things.

Comment: No, they don't intersect

Comment: @celalk38: Again, what are the *values*?  Currently what you have is an `if` statement which is evaluating to `true`.  And your assertion is that it should evaluate to `false`.  So your next step is to *prove* that assertion.  Otherwise all you're essentially asking is why an `if` block executes on a `true` condition.  It may be the case that you think they *shouldn't* intersect.  But that's a different problem than whether or not they *do* intersect.